# Querying titan graph for only indexed vertices without traversing complete graph

Tags: graph, bigdata, titan, gremlin

I am trying to retrieve only indexed vertices in the graph

I used the below query

```
Iterator<Vertex> vertices = titanTransaction.query().has("name").vertices().iterator();
```

This query traverses to the complete graph and fetches the result, Can anyone suggest me a better way,  The name vertex is indexed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `.has(key,value)` method https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/0.5.4/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/query/graph/GraphCentricQueryBuilder.java#L113

`Iterator<Vertex> vertices = titanTransaction.query().has("name","john").vertices().iterator();`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
graph.V('name','nameOfTargetVertex').next()
```

I think this should use your index on the attribute `name`, according to http://gremlindocs.com/#transform/v .